# Problems importing GlobalStyles into the app.tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I'm working with next13 and styled-components. In my file `globalStyles.ts` everything is fine (apparently), and before everything worked perfectly. But after a while, the `<GloobalStyles/>` import started to have errors.

This:

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type
> 'TemplateStringsArray': raw, length, concat, join, and 23
> more.ts(2740) (alias) const GlobalStyles:
> NamedExoticComponent<ExecutionProps & TemplateStringsArray> import
> GlobalStyles

This is the `_app.tsx` file:

```js
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import {GlobalStyles} from '../styles/global/GlobalStyles';
import theme from '../styles/theme';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <GlobalStyles />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the `'../styles/global/GlobalStyles'` not in the `_app.tsx`. Check the types there or share the code from that file.